# Sets with cardinality strictly greater an c

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Are there any examples of uncountably infinite sets with cardinality strictly greater than c other than the power set of the set of real numbers and the sequence of strictly larger sets obtained by constructing a sequence of uncountably infinite sets by creating the power set of the predecessor set, beginning with the real numbers?  I.e., with cardinality other than c,2<sup>c</sup>,2<sup>2<sup>c</sup></sup>,...?

This question is not a duplicate of the question "What infinity is greater than the continuum?" This question asks if there are any infinite cardinal numbers that are not elements of the countably infinite set {c,2<sup>c</sup>,2<sup>2<sup>c</sup></sup>,...}. Equivalently, does N is an infinite cardinal number imply N is an element of {c,2<sup>c</sup>,2<sup>2<sup>c</sup></sup>,...}?

Comment: It is consistent with ZFC that the answer is no, this is called the generalized continuum hypothesis. It is also consistent with ZFC that the answer is yes. Though you must be careful about what you mean by "sequence", since this hierarchy is actually very large (not just a sequence).

Comment: It's a sequence, a countably infinite one in fact, with cardinality (aleph)sub-null. .

Comment: And that's not the same question at all.  the cardinality of the power set of R is 2^c which is strictly greater than c.  The cardinality of the power set of the power set of the reals is 2^(2^c) which is strictly greater than 2^c, like I said in my question, which you should probably read.

Comment: Anyway, I figured it out a few hours after I posted my question. The answer is no, within ZFC.

Comment: What I am saying is that it is consistent with ZFC that sets of all infinite cardinalities can be obtained from a hierarchy of applications of the power set operation to a set of cardinality $\aleph_0$, then to a set of cardinality $c$, then to a set of cardinality $2^c$, etc. This statement is called the generalized continuuum hypothesis. However, the hierarchy that you get from doing this is called the beth numbers, and they are parametrized by *all ordinals*, not just a single copy of the natural numbers.

Comment: It is also consistent with ZFC that there are other sets entirely, for instance there can be a set of cardinality strictly between $\beth_1=c$ and $\beth_2=2^c$, even when there is no set of cardinality strictly between $\beth_0=\aleph_0$ and $\beth_1$. But because of the consistency between GCH and ZFC, it is basically hopeless to try to conceive of an example.

Comment: The set$$\mathbb R\cup\mathcal P(\mathbb R)\cup\mathcal P(\mathcal P(\mathbb R))\cup\cdots$$ has cardinality $$c+2^c+2^{2^c}+\cdots$$ which is greater than every cardinal in the sequence you mentioned.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you.

Comment: Note that we can continue this hierarchy beyond $\omega$: we let $\beth_{\alpha+1}=2^{\beth_\alpha}$ and $\beth_\lambda=\sup\{\beth_\beta: \beta<\lambda\}$ for $\lambda$ a limit. This hierarchy is unbounded (although unless the Generalized Continuum Hypothesis holds, it does not contain every cardinal): $\vert\alpha\vert\le \beth_\alpha$.

Comment: Your second question was asked before, although the counting began by $\aleph_0, 2^{\aleph_0}, 2^{2^{\aleph_0}},\ldots$, so if it's not a duplicate of one, it is a duplicate of another. And for what it's worth, in the [current] duplicate you can find an answer of mine, that under the failure of $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}=(2^{\aleph_0})^+$, gives an example of a cardinal which is not the cardinality of a power-set iteration from $\Bbb N$.